# Specify redirect after password reset

Tags: redirects, solspace-user, password

Is there any way to specify which template to redirect to after a user resets their password?

Currently, it takes them back to my reset password form, which is odd.

Comment: Are you using any add-ons for member management, or just the native tools?

Comment: I'm using Solspace User.

Comment: It doesn't appear that User has that functionality unfortunately. I know Profile:Edit from MightyBigRobot does, however, as long as you're using EE 2.7 with the new password reset functionality.

Comment: I using EE 2.6.1.

Comment: I just updated to 2.7.1 and get the same results. What is the new password reset functionality?

Comment: You're right about User: as of this writing, User's "forgot password" form sends you an email with a URL pointing to an **EE native** member template containing the password reset form. The form, the template, and redirection after submission isn't controlled by User.

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter "return" such as return="page/entry_id". Or get the MO'Variables Add-on and use return="{last_page_visited}".

Comment: How do you add the return parameter to the form? Does the {form_declaration} in the Password Reset Form member template accept parameters?

Comment: Are you using a custom form, or an EE form, or something created by third party?

To add the parameter its just like adding the parameter to a channel entries tag.

Comment: I'm using the default form in the member templates and just tried {form_declaration return="account/login"} but that breaks the form declaration tag and does not work.